# What Would Be a Best Practice to Uniquely specify an Entry With a Boolean Flag in the Database?

Tags: sql, database-design, nosql, entity-relationship

Let's assume that we have a collection (or table) that is called students, and in our system, we need to persist the best student of all time, which is going to be one and only one among all the students we have.
The first thing that came to my mind was to add IsBestStudent property (flag) to the Student class, but thinking about it I think it is naive to add a new field say for one million students just to have one with the value true.
What would be a good practice to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: There are many ways and it depends of the database type (nosql vs relational), if you need to persist there is no other way to add a column and if not you can use an aggregate function that returns the best student.

Comment: why is this tagged mysql and nosql?  which is it?

Comment: @ysth I used the two tags because I felt that the problem is more about the database design techniques and not related to the engine type, sorry if this caused confusion for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE BestStudent (
  student_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student(student_id)
);
```

This table has just one row, so it must reference only one student. You don't need a new column in the `Student` table, you only need that table to have a primary key for this little table to reference.

If you really only want to keep the single best student, then you should simply never insert any more rows. Update the current row if a new student beats the former best student's performance.

You might also want to use this table to store a history of the best students, in which case you would keep multiple rows. It's up to you. But the point is that you can use this technique to avoid adding a column to millions of rows in the student table. This table is bound to stay small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought of doing so also but wasn't sure if introducing another table with one entry all the time would be accepted. Also, I thought that using a key-value store might be convenient in this case, but the drawback here is that we now may have to add additional technology to the infrastructure.

Comment: I treat tables like I treat variables in my application code. I create a new variable if I need to. I would not, for example, append an unrelated value onto an array just to save a variable.